# React Redux props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, redux

Я начал изучать React, для написания фронта для своих сервисов, столкнулся с такой проблемой:
написал reducer и начальное состояние вытянул из своего api. Это файл с редьюсером

```
const initialState = getInitialState();
        
function getInitialState() {
    const initialState = {
        hotelList: [],
    };

    API.get('/hotels')
    .then((response) => {
        initialState['hotelList'] = response.data
    })
    
    return initialState;
}

export const hotelReducer = (state = initialState) => {
    return state;
}
```

Далее в основном компоненте я подключил стор и пытаюсь получить значение hotelList:

```
import Header from './components/Header/Header'

const App = (props) => {
  console.log(props.auth.testArr)
  console.log(props.hotels)
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <Header isLoggedIn={props.auth.isLoggedIn}/>
          <Route path='/login' component={LoginForm}/>
          <Route exact path='/' component={() => <HotelList hotelList={props.hotels.hotelList}/>} />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = store => {
  return {
    auth: store.auth,
    hotels: store.hotels,  
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

Когда я вывожу в консоль props.hotels, то там видно мой hotelList:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но когда я пытаюсь вывести props.hotels.hotelList, то выводится пустой массив:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите разобраться с проблемой

Answer (score 0):

Основная ошибка тут:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

connect (даже исходя из названия присоединяется к Provider
В Provider передается store, созданный с помощью createStore